# Add data to a csv and increase one of the values

Tags: php, arrays, forms, associative-array

Hello im gonna try to explain well this, its a little confusing

I have a .csv file, name users.csv with this format:

```
id name surname email
```

and with this data:

```
1 paul   harrison  test@test.com
2 robin  martinez  test@test.com
3 alma   halford   test@test.com
```

The thing is that i need to introduce the data from a form in to the csv, but the id element is not introduced when we get the data from the form, how can i do to increase id in one and add at the same time the data following the id in the same line?

```html
<form style="text-align: center;" method="post">
    name: <input type="text" name="name">
    <br><br>
    surname: <input type="text" name="surname">
    <br><br>
    Email: <input type="email" name="mail">
    <br><br>
    Password: <input type="password" name="pwd">
    <br><br>
    smartphone: <input type="tel" name="smart">
    <br><br>
    city: <input type="text" name="city">
    <br><br>
    C.P: <input type="number" name="cp">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="send">
</form>
```

To add more information the idea is that the id column from the csv is increased each time is added data to the users.csv, each time we write data in the csv the id file is increased in one.

Comment: Ok so if the form does not know about the `id` how are you going to find the right line in the CSV to add the new data too

Comment: It would be useful if you showed us the `<form>`

Comment: Ok, so you will have to read each line of the file, writing the unmatched lines as you go to a new file. When you find a match for `name` and `surname` and `email` then add the new data to that line then write that line, then write all the remaining lines to the file. Databases are sooooo much easier to deal with

Comment: trying something different, its possible to select the last id value from the csv file and do a increase of  1? dont know how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to realize auto-increment behaviour like in SQL, just find a maximum ID and increase it on one. Result is your new identifier for new row.

So to find maximum:

```php
$csv = ''; // here you csv
$max = 0;
foreach (explode("\n", $csv) as $row) {
  foreach (explode("\t", $row) as $index => $col) {
    if ($index == 0 && (int)$col > $max)
      $max = (int)$col;
  }
}
```

So as result you get maximum ID in `$max` variable. Just increase it on one and you have new identifier for new row as I say earlier.